# Enqueuing stylesheets wordpress not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress to create my website and doing a custom theme from scratch. I have in my child-theme's `function.php` this function:

```
function css_custom_assets() {
// Charger les CSS
wp_enqueue_style( 'sidebar', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/sidebar.css', array(), NULL, NULL);
wp_enqueue_style( 'structure', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/structure.css', array(), NULL, NULL);
wp_enqueue_style( 'loading', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/loading.css', array(), NULL, NULL);
wp_enqueue_style( 'header', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/header.css', array(), NULL, NULL);
wp_enqueue_style( 'footer', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/footer.css', array(), NULL, NULL);

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_styles', 'css_custom_assets', 10 );
```

Those are the main stylesheets. But they seem to be not added...

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks all.

Comment: Do no `link` elements for these get added to the HTML output? Or do you get 404s because the paths are not correct? (Use browser console to check for the latter.)

Comment: Nop, no links are added... But in every of my php files, i enqueue specific css files and it works well. It's only when i use this add_action...

Comment: Just a comment regarding best practices, `get_stylesheet_uri()` should only be used when fetching the actual `style.css` file. For the rest you should use `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Comment: Also you should register them first instead of enqueuing straight away. Right now you're loading everything at the same time but sometime your `index.php` file dont require the same css as your `signle.php` file. You should put in place some type of conditions around your enqueuing. Always register first with `wp_register_style` then enqueue. eg: `if( is_single() ){ wp_enqueue_style( 'sidebar', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/sidebar.css', array(), NULL, NULL ); };`

Comment: @marinediary that’s not true. In fact the get directory functions both have different purposes:  `get_template_directory_uri()` gets the *parent* theme folder whereas `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` gets the *current* theme folder (regardless of whether it’s a child theme or not). And you don’t need to register first - in fact that’s only necessary if you are loading the style sheet in a different location or under only some circumstances- otherwise it’s perfectly fine to enqueue only.

Answer (score 2):

Correct hook name is

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'css_custom_assets' );
```